# Western Europe Lonely Planet Travel Guide for a trip from Paris to Milan for Expo Milano

Tags: paris, guidebooks, milan

I intend to travel from Paris to Milan (and other cities on the way, if I have time). I'm going to buy [Western Europe Lonely Planet Travel Guide](http://www.booktopia.com.au/western-europe-lonely-planet/prod9781742204192.html) for guidance.

Is this a good book for my purpose?
Is this edition suitable?
any recommendation?

I'm attending a conference in Paris. After that I want travel from Paris to Milan for Expo Milano (2015).

(I think it is an interesting expo. Is this true?)

So I need low budget but interesting travel from Paris to Milan (or other cities on the way) with little luggage (only my laptop and clothes) for about 6 to 12 days (depends on costs).

Is this book helpful and is this Expo good?

time : October - September

Comment: What's your purpose exactly? Reaching Paris from Milan as efficiently as possible? Finding interesting things to do on the way? Are you a budget travellers/backpacker? Looking for info on the culture and historical sights? Sports and outdoor activities? Partying? Food? France and Italy are among the most popular tourist destinations in Europe, if not the whole world, there are probably dozens of guides to choose from. It's also a part of the world where it is very easy to travel or find good info online, so you could very easily forgo getting a guide entirely.

Comment: @Relaxed. Thank you for comment. I added some information.

Comment: Note that the Lonely Planet sells ebooks by the chapter, so you can buy the Paris chapter of France guidebook and the Milan chapter of Italy guidebook. That's cheaper and lighter

Comment: @Vince, the OP is also looking for guidance about cities along the route.

Comment: @jpatokal yeah it's just a suggestion on the format of the guidebooks. From what I saw before, the Lonely Planet offers any level of details one wishes (e.g. taking the Northern Italy chapter, the Lombardy chapter, the Milan and area chapter, the Milan chapter). So it is possible to mix and match chapters of different books (France, Eastern France, Northern Italy) to find all the information for the whole trip.

Comment: Isn't this a `recommendations` question?

Comment: @JoErNanO. No. why do you have this idea?

Answer (score 2):

The Western Europe edition will hold lots of information you are not going to use, which is a waste of money and carrying weight but you might use it at other times.
But the best reason not to buy this book but the France or even Paris book as well as an Italian is that the books covering a whole continent do not have much information on any location while the more limited area books have much more information on the same locations.

These days I would go without buying a guidebook for a few days of travel.
It is very likely that you can find a (Lonely Planet) guidebook covering the area in a library or as cheap secondhand in a shop near to you, to select the locations you want to use. But while traveling you can better use internet to get you the hostels.

And visit a good rail site to get your travel information. Seat 61 might be the best site: http://www.seat61.com/Paris-to-Milan-by-TGV-train.htm or try the French or Italian national sites.

Comment: Thank you foe answer. What's your idea about Expo Milano? Is it worth to travel from Paris to Milan to visit that?

Comment: I have never been on for the big expositions, so never have considered the Milano one. But if you WANT to go, do it. You are relatively near and it will be a good reason for some traveling.

Answer (score 2):

*If* this is your first trip to Europe (it sounds like it is?), and you're not really sure where you should go and what you should see, then I think the LP *Western Europe* is a **very reasonable choice** to start with.  (An alternative would be the somewhat misnamed [Mediterranean Europe](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/mediterranean-europe), which also covers Paris and Milan, but focuses more on the southern half of the continent.)

Both are designed pretty much exactly for people like you, and while it's not going to take you far off the beaten track, it's going to give you a pretty good idea of what's possible, how much it will cost, and a bunch of sample itineraries to work off, all in a format that's easier to deal with than a million random web pages.  You can cut costs a bit by buying the PDFs instead, or cut weight by buying the guide and physically cutting out the chapters you end up deciding you'll never need.

(*Disclaimer*: I used to work for Lonely Planet.)

Comment: Thank you for answer. For traveling Paris to Milan and maybe other cities in the  along the route which one is better? `Western Europe` or `Mediterranean Europe?

Comment: The direct line between those two points goes through France & Italy (in both), plus maybe Switzerland (in Western only).  But in this age of cheap flights you can easily add a stop somewhere else entirely, eg. Spain.

Comment: What's your idea about `Expo Milano`? Is it worth to travel from Paris to Milan to visit that?